# Magnific Popup appears below page on mobile

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm asking this question here because the Magnific Popup docs said this was the best place for questions.

I'm having an odd issue, on smaller windows and mobile the popup appears below the page and you have to scroll down to it. I haven't had this issue before and I was hoping someone else had.

You can check the demo site at http://seemywebsite.org/customreserves/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use media queries and override the required classes, for the mobile versions.

Comment: It resizes just fine, it's just positioned below the window and you have to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone else who may have this problem. I'd applied padding to the popup, and that was breaking the layout, so adding box-sizing:border-box worked. Phew.